# jQuery.parseJSON stop working when passed more data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a script that query a database and echo out a json code with the results.
The javascript takes that and store in a variable using `jQuery.parseJSON` method then populates a text box to do an autocomplete.
Everything works perfect if I return less than 30 rows on the database query.
It looks that `jQuery.parseJSON` method fails when I passed to it more data.

How to change the code to make it able to parse more data?

Thank you for all your help.

JSON Code:

```
{
    "display":true,
    "url":"http://project-url",
    "autoComplete":
    [
        {
            "value":"1",
            "desc":"Ford",
            "model":"Edge",
            "label":"1 Ford Edge"
        },
        {
            "value":"2",
            "desc":"Toyota",
            "model":"Camry",
            "label":"2 Toyota Camry"
        },
        {
            "value":"3",
            "desc":"Honda",
            "model":"Accord",
            "label":"3 Honda Accord"
        },
        {
            "value":"4",
            "desc":"Honda",
            "model":"Civic",
            "label":"4 Honda Civic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(jsonVar);

$('#value-input').autocomplete(
{
    source: data.autoComplete,
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui)
    {
        $('#desc-input').val(ui.item.desc);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post code snippets.

Comment: `jQuery.parseJSON` has no such limitation. The script that's querying the database must be generating invalid JSON. Maybe there's a character encoding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without any code we can only make assumptions, in that case Jquery.ParseJSON support bigger data, probably the problem is the json, maybe some character is broking the json or something that is not related to the size of the rows that returns the database.

You can validate the json [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

can you include the json that produce the error? or can you validate the json in the link that I provided above for check if the problem is into the json?

Comment: Yes, I used that validation website before post the question and gave me a valid JSON format. If I use less that 30 elements it works. More than that stop working.

Comment: the Json that produce the error is the same that you posted in the question?

Comment: Yes, but with more elements, like 150 more. But when I validated de JSON return valid JSON.

Comment: probably in the console is showing a error, can you copy that? I also made and example that you can use for test your json, http://jsfiddle.net/DlanorJQ/o48rvcd7/

Comment: between the (Brake Line Blank Space) exists a couple of ","

Comment: no, just that, a break line in blank. That was the issue a brake line on the element. It comes from the database with that break line I remove it and it works perfectly. Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the data comes with a break line in one of its elements. Number 2, break line between **value** and **desc** elements. It was a valid JSON format but jQuery for some reason doesn't like it. I just remove the break line and it works.Thank you Ronald !!

```
{
    "display":true,
    "url":"http://project-url",
    "autoComplete":
    [
        {
            "value":"1",
            "desc":"Ford",
            "model":"Edge",
            "label":"1 Ford Edge"
        },
        {
            "value":"2

            ",
            "desc":"Toyota",
            "model":"Camry",
            "label":"2 Toyota Camry"
        },
        {
            "value":"3",
            "desc":"Honda",
            "model":"Accord",
            "label":"3 Honda Accord"
        },
        {
            "value":"4",
            "desc":"Honda",
            "model":"Civic",
            "label":"4 Honda Civic"
        }
    ]
}
```